# How do I change the difficulty on the first level of Thief: Deadly Shadows?

Tags: thief-deadly-shadows

I just started playing Thief: Deadly Shadows.  I'm trying to change the difficulty on the first mission: Checking Inn - Cashing Out, but nothing works!

**How do I change the difficulty level?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first mission is a tutorial.  There is only one difficulty setting available.**